# How to calculate the median values without NAs?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df
name    var1  var2  var3  var4  var5 ...
site1    10    20    12    5     ..
site2    15    NA    11    2     ..
site3    NA    11    21    1     ..
site4    9     18    NA    6     ..
```

I use this code to calculate the median of the columns.

```
apply(df[,c(2:4)], 2, median)
```

But it gives NA for columns 2 to 4, because they have NA values. How to exclude the NA values and still calculate medians from the rest data in each column? If use na.rm=T for a subset, all rows with NAs will be removed, which is not what I want. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
df<-data.frame("a"=c(1,2,3, 4), "b"=c(1,NA,4, 5))

medianWithoutNA<-function(x) {
   median(x[which(!is.na(x))])
}

apply(df, 2, medianWithoutNA)
  a   b 
2.5 4.0
```

btw you can write

```
apply(df[,2:4], 2, median)
```

without `c()`

Please tell me if the solution works for you and if yes, accept my answer.

This is the code if you want to compute the median per site:

```
df<-data.frame(name=c("site1", "site1", "site2", "site2", "site3"), a=c(1, 2, 3, 1, 3), b=c(3, 2, 3, 1,4))
aggregate(cbind(a, b) ~ name, data=df, medianWithoutNA)
```

Comment: You can just use `apply(df, 2, function (x) median(x, na.rm = TRUE) )`, or even better `apply(df[, 2:4], 2, median, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: @ssdecontrol ah ok, I did not know that, I thought that's what the OP meant.

Comment: I found that there are some rows have the same name, some are not. So is it possible to calculate the medians for rows with same names, like classify? The results should be several median values for each variable, according to the names. Thanks.

Comment: @Lily I'm pretty sure it is possible, can you add an example to your original question? Just that I am sure what you mean :)

Comment: Yes, the name column, each row has the name like this: site 1, site 1, site1, site 2, site 3, site 4, site 4, etc. How to calculate the median for site 1, site 2, and so on separately? And is it possible to add the name also, so I know which name corresponds to what medians? Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Use `lapply`, which does not convert to a matrix.

```
lapply(df[2:4], median, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
for (i in 2:4) {
  print(median(df[,i],na.rm=T))
}
```

Or with column names:

```
for (i in 2:4) {
  print(paste("Median",colnames(df)[i],"=",median(df[,i],na.rm=T)))
}
```

Comment: Welcome mcam to SO - some advice focus on new unanswered questions and not old questions. Your answers are unlikely to get much traction (nor add much).

Comment: Your answer does only print the resulting values in the console window but they can't be used for further computations. The OP has used `apply()` in his Q, so it's likely that simply printing might not be sufficient.